# Convert Array Object to new Array Object (using angular)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

> I have array Object

```
[
{ testTargetname: "Test system", in: 2, low: 1, medium: 2 },
{ testTargetname: "Test app", in: 2, low: 1, medium: 0 }]
```

> I don't know how to convert to the new array object below. Please help me

```
[
{ in: 1, testTargetname: "Test system" },
{ in: 1, testTargetname: "Test system" },
{ low: 1, testTargetname: "Test system" },
{ medium: 1, testTargetname: "Test system" },
{ medium: 1, testTargetname: "Test system" },
{ medium: 1, testTargetname: "Test system" },
{ in: 1, testTargetname: "Test app" },
{ in: 1, testTargetname: "Test app" },
{ low: 1, testTargetname: "Test app" },
```

]

> When medium = 0, It's not displayed in new array

Comment: model of first OBJECT interface Luck { testTargetName: string; in: Inumber;low:number;medium: number; }

Comment: Have you tried using the [map fuction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?retiredLocale=nl) already?

Comment: And you could use the [flat fuction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten your jagged array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and inside the callback iterate the current object and check if the value of the current key is number and greater than 0

```js
let data = [{
    testTargetname: "Test system",
    in: 2,
    low: 1,
    medium: 2
  },
  {
    testTargetname: "Test app",
    in: 2,
    low: 1,
    medium: 0
  }
];

var val = data.reduce(function(d, a) {
  for (const b in a) {
    if (!isNaN(a[b]) && 0 < a[b]) {
      for (var e = 0; e < a[b]; e++) {
        d.push({testTargetname : a.testTargetname, [b] : 1});
      }
    }
  }
  return d;
}, []);
console.log(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [
    { testTargetname: "Test system", in: 2, low: 1, medium: 2 },
    { testTargetname: "Test app", in: 2, low: 1, medium: 0 }]

let createObject = (_object, _key) => {
    const newKeyArray = []
    for(let i = 0; i < _object[_key] || 0; i++){
        let newObject = {}
        newObject[_key] = 1//_object[_key]
        newObject["testTargetname"] = _object["testTargetname"]        
        newKeyArray.push(newObject)
    }
    return newKeyArray;
}
newArray = [];
array.forEach( (_object) => {
    ["in", "low", "medium"].forEach((_key) => {
        newArray.push( ...createObject(_object, _key) )
    })
})
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a JavaScript/TypeScript question as it doesn't really have anything to do with Angular.

```
const source = [
  { testTargetname: "Test system", in: 2, low: 1, medium: 2 },
  { testTargetname: "Test app", in: 2, low: 1, medium: 0 },
];

source.reduce((result, item) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(item).filter((key) => key !== "testTargetname");
  const itemsToAdd = keys.reduce((response, key) => {
    let addToResponse: Record<string, string | number>[];
    for (let i = 1; i <= item[key]; i++) {
      [...addToResponse, { [key]: 1, testTargetname: item.testTargetname }];
    }
    return !!addToResponse ? [...response, ...addToResponse] : response;
  }, [] as Record<string, string | number>[]);
  return [...result, ...itemsToAdd];
}, [] as Record<string, string | number>[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see nobody tried flatMap, so please have a look at my solution

```js
   const list = [
  {
    testTargetname: 'Test system',
    in: 2,
    low: 1,
    medium: 2
  },
  {
    testTargetname: 'Test app',
    in: 2,
    low: 1,
    medium: 0
  }
]

const newList = list.flatMap((currentItem) => {
  const targetKey = 'testTargetname'
  return Object.entries(currentItem)
    .filter(([key]) => key !== targetKey)
    .map((item) => {
      const obj = Object.fromEntries([item])
      return {
        ...obj,
        [targetKey]: currentItem[targetKey]
      }
    })
})

console.log(newList)
```

PS, it is an example of how to map it to the proper structure, but if you want to filter some particular values then at the end just use the `filter` function